# Add MultiLine smiley in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edtInput"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="2"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
   android:gravity="top|left"
   android:padding="4dp"
   android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Hi, I read many questions similar to my question but still i could not find any solution. I am making one chat application in that i want to add smileys in `EditText`. But i am facing one problem when i m adding any smiley it add in `EditText` it continue to the end of line but when next line is come first line is not shown. Please help me to solve this . This is my code snippet where i am adding smiley into edittext.

```
AddSpannable(Bitmap bitmap, Context context,String filePath) {

        Drawable d = null;
        if (MainActivity.edtInput != null) {

            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(MainActivity.edtInput
                    .getEditableText().append(" "));
            ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(
                    filePath, 100, 100), ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

            ss.setSpan(span, ss.length() -1, ss.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            MainActivity.edtInput.setText(ss);
            MainActivity.edtInput.setSelection(ss.length());


        }
    }
```

Comment: I got solution after very large research....